# Why is Update Cursor adding Object IDs incorrectly?

Tags: arcpy

I am using an update cursor to add values in a try:except block of code using ArcPy.  If the code is successful I log `yes` in the `success` field, if it reaches the except block I log `yes` in the `fail` field.  I also log the time of the succeeds or fail.  However, my Object ID is doing very strange things.

The first two object IDs populated this table on one execution of the script, the others came at 2 other times.  I would ideally like to see 1-6, not 1,2,401,402,801,802 as noted in the screenshot.

[image]

code snippet which reflects table

```
except:
rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(aTable)
for x in xrange(0, outputobjects):
    row = rows.newRow()
row.setValue("Success", 'NO')
row.setValue("Fail", 'YES')
row.setValue("Time", Start)
rows.insertRow(row)
logger.exception("Something has gone wrong!")
print "the try has failed!"

try:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(failhandletest)
except:
    logger.exception("This works for the nested exception and fail has been logged in History_Table")
    rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(aTable)

for x in xrange(0, outputobjects):
    row = rows.newRow()
row.setValue("Success", 'NO')
row.setValue("Fail", 'YES')
row.setValue("Time", Start)
rows.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: What version of ArcGIS do you work with?

Answer (score 4):

Yes this behaviour could seem strange but it's perfectly normal.

Object Ids are managed by the geodatabase system, which maybe jump from 2 to 400 in case of the first process is still running.

If you want ids from 1 to 6 for your features, you have to populate your own field `ID` than the system field `OBJECTID`. At the start of your script, get the max value of `ID`, then increase it each time your insert a new row.

Comment: To add to this answer, I'm not at my pc to test this but I think you can compact a database to reset the sequence or is export? Never can remember!

Comment: superrache, do you have an example of this?

Comment: nop, and I am not very python friendly (more Java). At the start of the script, check the existence of the field ID, create it if it doesnt exist. Then, with a search cursor, iterate each feature of your table to get the max of row.getValue("ID").